# ORM works, Declarative doesn't. Why?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This should be self explanatory. I am able to expose a database through the Object Relational approach (ORM), but not through the Declarative approach. Am I failing to instantiate the class? What is the missing step here?

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String

engine = create_engine('my connection details', echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base()

my_table = Table('my_table', 
    Base.metadata, 
    autoload=True, 
    autoload_with=engine, 
    schema='my_schema')

class MyClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    int_col = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    str_col = Column(String)

>>> for stuff in session.query(my_table).all():
...     print stuff # Works perfectly

>>> for stuff in session.query(MyClass).all():
...     print stuff # DatabaseError: table or view does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MyClass(Base):
    __table__ = my_table
    int_col = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    str_col = Column(String)
```

Declarative creates table for each mapper, so 'my_table' in declarative is other table.
You may also use database reflection:

```
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData(bind=engine)
metadata.reflect()

class MyClass(Base):
    __table__ = metadata.tables['my_table']
    int_col = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    str_col = Column(String)
```